# Lucene Incomplete Word Spellchecking

Tags: lucene, spell-checking, levenshtein-distance

I am using Lucene to perform spell checking. I am using 
https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html

What I really want is, for example, I have a word:
spellingmistake

And now I type:
speli.

In this case, I want to spellchecker to return me the correct word or at least return spell. So to achieve this while indexing the dictionary in the indexwriter config I used a EdgeNGramTokenizer assuming it would work for this case. But unfortunately, it is not working.

How do I get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: What I can think of is manually creating a new document for each substring of the original word. But that would drastically decrease performance.